# What happens with an excerpt from a site the user hasn't access to?

Tags: confluence

Imagine the following scenario:

```
- Parentsite (open for whole space)
  - Childsite (readable for User A only)
```

Parentsite contains an excerpt from Childsite. User A of sees the site correctly with the excerpt. But what happens with User B? Does he see the excerpt anyway? Does he get a warning instead of the actual content?